# How to use echo and substr in one line?

Tags: php

I need help. Basically I am trying to make a blog and I want to display some posts on main page but I dont know how to limit number of characters from content.
Here is my code:

```
<?php foreach($query as $q){ ?>
    <div class="card" style="margin: 5px; width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $q['title'];?></h5>
            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $q['content'];?></p>
            <a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $q['id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Read more...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

I tried this:

```
<?php foreach($query as $q){ ?>
    <div class="card" style="margin: 5px; width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $q['title'];?></h5>
            <p class="card-text"><?php substr(echo $q['content'];,0, 50)?></p>
            <a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $q['id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Čítaj ďalej...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

and much more solutions but it did not help.
Some help please?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to set a max number of characters for some some text.

Change the style to select the number of lines you want to show. The `-webkit-line-clamp: 4;` will be responsible to tell the max number of lines you want to have:

```
<style>
.card-text{
    width:100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
</style>
```

If you want the content in only one line:

```
<style>
.card-text{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style>
```

But if the goal is really to hide 100% the content from the user using your backend, the previous methods shown by the others using php substrig is enough.

Comment: #upvoted, for thinking outside the box of PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$string = "Oi, eu sou o matheus. Texto adicional";
echo substr($string, 0, 2); // outputs Oi
echo substr($string, 4, 16); // eu sou o matheus
```

Answer (score 0):

substr(echo $q['content'];,0, 50); is not going to output the data you want . (substr is a PHP function to get a part of a string say from position x and length y with the syntax substr($string, x, y))

Please change

```
<?php substr(echo $q['content'];,0, 50)?>
```

to

```
<?php echo substr($q['content'],0,50); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Errors

1. The syntactic error when you added `;` inside of the function.
2. Putting `echo` which returns `void` where `substr` expects a `string`.

## Correction

```
<?= substr($q['content'],0, 50) ?>
```

## Recommendation

You can shorten you PHP echo inside of the HTML templates using  the **short echo tag**

```php
<?= $a ?>
```

Which is equivelent to

```php
<?php echo $a; ?>
```

## Example

```php
<?php
$content = "
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and Ipsum.
";
?>

<?= substr($content,0, 50) ?>
```

Test https://3v4l.org/HHbZQ

Answer (score 0):

Here you go and if var not exists echo something random with **??**

```
<?php

 echo  substr(($q['title'] ?? 'sometext'), 0, 30);
    
?>
```

And with a function to check or something else

```
<?php

 echo substr(MYFUNCTION($q['title'] ?? 'sometext'), 0, 50);

?>
```